# How Can I Go About Writing A Javascript/PHP Parser To Transfer Data In Buttons To My Database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, database

I'm working on creating a tag system for users to be able to tag their profiles, the visual end of the system is working and is really simplistic, it's a 2 divs, one for selectedTags one for unselectedTags, there's like 30+ tags that appear in the unselectedTags div from the start, and on click if there is less than 5 tags currently selected it will move unselectedTags to selectedTags, users can click selected tags to 1) if the tag was originally in the unselectedTags div, move it back to the unselectedTags div, or 2) if it was user entered, it simply deletes the tag. I want to simply store the text data from the tags that are within the selectedTags div into the database, hopefully within like a single tags[] array, the user can enter tags so it'd be best if the parser would be able to access the innerHTML of the buttons, the issue is I'm really unsure of how to go about this, can I write a javascript parser to extract this data on submit button click? And how should I go about storing the tags[] until the submit button is pressed/how can I extract the tags[] when the submit button is pressed? The database doesn't have a user entry for this user yet because the DB entry isn't created until form submission so, I may be very wrong here and if I am that'd be lit, but I don't think I can simply directly push the data on click of the buttons to the database bc there isn't an entry for the user yet.

This is the setup for what I have working:

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<form action="" class="inputGroup" id="artistRegister" method="post">
<div class="tagSelect">
   <h2 class="tagHeader">Select Up To 5 Tags That Describe Your Style, Or</h2>
   <input type="text" name="inputTag" id="inputTag" class="inputTag" placeholder="Enter Your Own...">
   <div class="selectedTags" id="selectedTags">

   </div>

   <div class="unselectedTags smooth" id="unselectedTags">
      <button type="button" class="artistTag grafitti">Grafitti</button>
      <button type="button" class="artistTag minimalism">Minimalism</button>
      <button type="button" class="artistTag abstract">Abstract</button>
      <button type="button" class="artistTag flowers">Flowers</button>
      <button type="button" class="artistTag modern">Modern</button>
      <button type="button" class="artistTag street">Street</button>
      <!--...-->

      <!--I've been looking for help on this problem as well and got the recommendation to try
       setting the buttons up like checkboxes with a specific name and value to no avail-->
   </div>
</div>

<!--More form...-->

<!--button type="submit" name="submit" class="artistRegisterBtn">Register</button-->
</form>
<script src="login.js"></script>
</html>
```

```css
.selectedTags {
    max-width: 360px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-height: 0px;
    max-height: 65px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display:none;
}

.selectedTags::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 4px;
}

.selectedTags::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#inputTag {
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    user-select: none;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

#inputTag::placeholder {
    color: white;
}

.tagHeader {
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    user-select: none;
}

.artistTag {
    background-color: rgb(25, 34, 58);
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    user-select: none;
}

.artistTag:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.unselectedTags {
    margin-top: 10px;
    max-height: 70px;
    min-height: 40px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    user-select: none;
}

.unselectedTags::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;
}

.unselectedTags::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.tagSelect {
    max-height: 176px;
}
```

```js
//This works, however for some reason the user input field is autosubmitting 
//when pressing enter, normally on the actual form it doesn't submit, I honestly 
//have no idea why this is happening, my guess is it sees there's only a couple 
//elements and instead of taking the enter key press as input it's just taking enter 
//as submit even though on the fully fleshed out form it doesn't, idk what's causing 
//this behavior but hopefully you can get a decent idea of how the system works
var list1 = document.getElementById("selectedTags");
var list2 = document.getElementById("unselectedTags");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var tags = document.querySelectorAll(".artistTag");
    var userTags = document.querySelectorAll(".userEntry");

    function moveItem(e) {
        userTags = document.querySelectorAll(".userEntry");
        var moveTo = this.parentElement == list1 ? list2 : list1;
        if(moveTo == list1 && list1.childElementCount < 5) {
            if(list1.childElementCount <= 1) {
                list1.style.borderBottom = "1px solid white";
                list2.style.height = "40px";
                list1.style.display = "block";
            }
            moveTo.insertBefore(this, list1.firstChild);
            this.style.margin = "2px";
        } else if(moveTo == list2) {
            if(list1.childElementCount == 1) {
                list1.style.borderBottom = "0px solid white";
                list2.style.height = "70px";
                list1.style.display = "none";
            }
            moveTo.insertBefore(this, list2.firstChild);
            this.style.margin = "2px";
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        tags[i].addEventListener("click", moveItem);
    }
});

function deleteItem(e) {
    userTags = document.querySelectorAll(".userEntry");
    if(list1.childElementCount == 1) {
        list1.style.borderBottom = "0px solid white";
        list2.style.height = "70px";
        list1.style.display = "none";
    }
    this.remove();
}

$(document).on("keydown", ":input:not(textarea)", function(event) {
    return event.key != "Enter";
});

$(".inputTag").on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
        if(list1.childElementCount < 5) {
            if(list1.childElementCount <= 1) {
                list1.style.borderBottom = "1px solid white";
                list2.style.height = "40px";
            }
            list1.style.display = "block";
            var input = document.createElement("button");
            input.innerHTML = inputTagText.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputTagText.value.slice(1);
            input.classList = "artistTag userEntry";
            input.type = "button";
            input.style.margin = "2px";
            list1.insertBefore(input, list1.firstChild);
            document.getElementById("inputTag").value = "";
            input.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);
        }
    }
});


$('.smooth').on('mousewheel', function(e){
    wheel(e.originalEvent, this)
  })
  
  function wheel(event, elm) {
      var delta = 0;
      if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
      else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;
  
      handle(delta, elm);
      if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = false;
  }
  
  function handle(delta, elm) {
      const time = 250;
        const distance = 20;
      
      $(elm).stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $(elm).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
      }, time );
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No, you should not be parsing any innerHTML or similar yourself here. First of all, move the relevant data that you currently have set as a class name, into either a custom data attribute, or into the `value` attribute of the buttons. Then you can access those attributes directly using standard DOM functionality, and don't have to do any "parsing" yourself.